# Content repeated in Joomla modal window

Tags: joomla2.5, modal-dialog, virtuemart

I'm having a really weird problem. When I click on Quick View the first time on

http://coderweb.info/tbps/index.php/shop/accessories

the content appears in the modal window as it should, namely once. The second time I click on any of the Quick View buttons, it appears twice (except for the image). The third time it appears thrice and so on. There is no loop anywhere in the code. The Quick View link is in the following format

http://coderweb.info/tbps/index.php/shop/accessories/universal-dual-tone-horns-detail?how=quick&tmpl=component

It basically loads the Virtuemart Product Detail page, but I have modified it so that when the 'how' parameter is passed with the value 'quick', it shows the 'Quick View' instead:

```
if(JRequest::getVar('how','') == 'quick'){
    echo $this->loadTemplate('quick');
    return;
}
```

What is causing this problem? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added

```
rel="{handler:'iframe'}"
```

to the link and that seems to have fixed it. I guess it was using a div element by default and it wasn't being cleared properly.